# How to configure pfsense to use LAN ports as local switched ports?

Tags: firewall, local-area-network, pfsense

I have a pfsense box with 6 LAN ports. I'd like to use one as the WAN port, and 5 as local LAN ports, just like a home gateway/router.  How to setup the LAN ports so that they are all in the same subnet?  It seems that the bridging function only wants to bridge between WAN and LAN?

Answer (score 3):

Three major steps are required for this:

**1)** Assign *and* enable all the additional interfaces. These will show up by default as OPT*n* interfaces. You can rename them to whatever you like (maybe LAN*n* instead?) - just be sure to enable them as well. Here is a screenshot of my interfaces:

[image: pfSense Interface Assignments]

**2)** Create a new bridge that has the original LAN interfaces and all of the LAN*n* as members.

[image: pfSnese Create Bridge]

**3)** Add a firewall rule to allow traffic across each interface of the bridge. I would suggest starting with a rule like "Protocol: any, Source: LAN subnet, Destination: LAN subnet". Depending on your needs you may also want to add a rule to allow internet access as well.

Comment: I hate dragging up old questions, but I would like to see this modernised for the latest version of pfSense. I'm trying to do this now and in the creation of the extra LANn interfaces, I have to assign an IP address for the port, but it can't be in the same subnet, although I need it to be.